# vim - show one file in several files consistently

Tags: vim, editor

I.e. is it possible in `vim` to edit large file in several simultaneously opened tabs in the following way: first part of text (that fill all vertical space), second - in the second pane, and so on.

if it is not possible in vim, maybe it's feature is implemented in other editors?

Comment: A while ago I've seen a plugin that did exactly what you describe, but I can't seem to remember its name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Synchronizes two vim panes**

Lets say your window is 20 rows, then

```
:vsplit                 // splits window into left and right panes
^w^w                    // focuses right pane
20^e                    // scrolls right pane down 20 rows
:windo set scrollbind   // syncronizes both panes
```

`^w` means press and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and then press <kbd>w</kbd>. Likewise for `^e`

`:windo` means `:set scrollbind` in all open panes

**Implement it in a function**

*Wraps the above commands in a function and binds it to* <kbd>[</kbd>

```
function! SyncScroll()
  vsplit                 
  execute "normal! \<c-w>\<c-w>" . winheight(0) . "\<c-e>"
  windo set scrollbind
endfunction

nnoremap [ :call SyncScroll()<cr>
```

---

You can add the above function and mapping to your vimrc with `:e $MYVIMRC` and reload it with `:source $MYVIMRC`

---

**ref:**

- [vim
  docs - scrollbinding](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-binding)
- [wiki - scrollbinding](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Scrolling_synchronously)

Comment: Thank you, this works. Maybe you know how to wrap this to a function?

Comment: I updated my answer with a function wrapper and key mapping

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [MPage plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4545). You probably want to install the latest version from [DrChip's page](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#MPAGE).